# echo $PATH return unexpected and unfamiliar - terminal error

Tags: python, macos, shell, command-line, terminal

After installing `GDAL` and `Fiona` via Homebrew, I can no longer access anything found in the /usr or /usr/local paths via the terminal. Prior to these installs, I've been accessing anything I care to using `python3.9 -m ...` such as `python3.9 -m pip install ...` or `python3.9 -m jupyter notebook`

Here is a copy of what my terminal looks like when trying to open `jupyter notebook`

```
my_name@name-MacBook-Pro ~ % python3.9 -m jupyter notebook
/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: No module named jupyter
```

When I echo the PATH, this is what is returned:

```
my_name@name-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/lib:/opt/homebrew/lib:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/ext/ghostscript/9.53.3_1/lib:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/ext/ghostscript/9.53.3_1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I'm no expert on CLI or terminal for MAC, but I am not familiar with the path `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9` or any of the paths above being main paths, in general or something that I would have set up.

It would appear that I somehow set the default path to some library within homebrew. That's my guess anyways.

I can temporarily fix the issue by executing `PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` and `export PATH`. However, if I restart terminal or the computer, the issue re-occurs.

How do I permanently change the default library back to reflect the paths shown when I run the above, which are the same as what's shown when I execute `sudo nano /etc/paths` which are:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who come to this looking for a solution, I was able to back-track to where the issue first began.

Somehow, I wrote to my machine's .zshrc file. All I had to do was open it up via the terminal, delete out the text that was mistakenly written, and save.

`nano ~/.zshrc`

delete out the mistakenly-written lines

`ctrl+X` to exit

`source .zshrc` to make the changes stick

Exit the terminal

done!